# Laravel 5.4 Eloquent query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I have a models:
Player,
Play,
Download,
Track

Relations:

```
Player has many Play and Download
Play and Download belongs to Player
Track has many Play and Download
```

I'm trying to find a query that gives me list of objects for a Track:

```
Track 
--Player
----Plays
----Downloads
--Player
----Plays
----Downloads
--Player
----Plays
----Downloads
```

I use it in vuejs data-table component:

```
<data-tables
    :data='data.players' 
    >
    <el-table-column 
      prop="place_title">
    </el-table-column>
    <el-table-column
      prop="plays.length">
    </el-table-column>
    <el-table-column
      prop="downloads.length">
    </el-table-column>
</data-tables>
```

If `groupBy` could works with an Eloquent object keys, it would be almost what I need:

```
$plays = $track->plays()->whereYear('created_at', $year )->whereMonth( 'created_at', $month )->with('player')->get();
$players = $plays->groupBy('player');
```

But `groupBy` works with a string keys so that's doesn't useful in my problem.

Comment: Hi, can I see the structure of the three tables?

Comment: Players: [link](http://icecream.me/uploads/5ff1dae239e5424fe4db5ca65451486c.png) Plays: [link](http://icecream.me/uploads/276e8e9611c4a31878a2a0e25ae332a6.png) Downloads: [link](http://icecream.me/uploads/276e8e9611c4a31878a2a0e25ae332a6.png)  Tracks: [link](http://icecream.me/uploads/a629b99a589fd3a18d2d8024e6170e47.png)

Comment: Okay, I posted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Without more information about the `plays()` method and others, the best I can say is the code you posted wouldn't work because `$plays` is a Collection. Try doing it this way (in this case, `$plays` is a Query Builder object):

```
$plays = $track->plays()->whereYear('created_at', $year )->whereMonth( 'created_at', $month )->with('player');
$players = $plays->groupBy('player')->get();
```

Comment: I've tried `groupBy('plays.player_id')` but there is an error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'muzoperator.plays.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select * from `plays` where `plays`.`track_id` = 15 and `plays`.`track_id` is not null and year(`created_at`) = 2017 and month(`created_at`) = 5 group by `plays`.`player_id`)

Answer (score 1):

I fell asleep yesterday, so couldn't respond sooner, but I think you might need something like this:

```
// Assumes you're already fetching the track e.g $track = Track::find($id);

$plays = $track->plays()->with('player')->get();
$plays = $plays->groupBy('player_id');

$downloads = $track->downloads()->with('player')->get();
$downloads = $downloads->groupBy('player_id');
```

The code snippet below is just an example of how you would call this data in a view page. [Screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMyOw.jpg)

```
<h4>Track {{ $track->id }} Plays</h4>
<ul>
  @foreach ($plays as $play)
   <li>Player id:{{ $play[0]->player->id }} has played {{ count($play) }} times</li>
  @endforeach
 </ul>
<b>Total plays: {{ count($track->plays) }}</b>

<h4>Track {{ $track->id }} Downloads</h4>
<ul>
 @foreach ($downloads as $download)
  <li>Player id:{{ $download[0]->player->id }} has downloaded {{ count($download) }} times</li>
 @endforeach
</ul>
<b>Total downloads: {{ count($track->downloads) }}</b>
```

Comment: That looks pretty nice... But I can't use it on my vujs data-table component (( You can see this component code on my edited question

Comment: Actually, I don't know vuejs. But maybe if you could explain what the purpose of the component is, and the output you're trying to achieve...

Comment: I expect that kind of json from laravel - [link](http://icecream.me/uploads/6212abd2f613cfcce817d482debbbe36.png)